# Start eclipse on system startup

Tags: java, eclipse, system

Is there any way to configure eclipse to start on system startup?

I'm looking for a way to configure my **Eclipse Oxygen** such that whenever I start my machine(with OS windows 10), it automatically start for some workspace.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows 7 and earlier versions of Windows, the Start menu contained a “Startup” folder to make this easy. On these versions of Windows, you can simply open your Start menu, locate a shortcut to an application you want to start automatically, right-click it, and select Copy. Next, locate the Startup folder under All Apps in the Start menu, right-click it, and select Paste to paste a copy of that shortcut.

This folder is no longer as easily accessible on Windows 8, 8.1, and 10, but it’s still accessible. To access it, press Windows Key + R, type “shell:startup” into the Run dialog, and press Enter. Shortcuts(here, the shortcut to your eclipse.exe) you add to the “shell:startup” folder will only launch when you log in with your user account. If you’d like a shortcut to launch itself whenever any user logs in, type “shell:common startup” into the Run dialog instead.

[Source](https://www.howtogeek.com/228467/how-to-make-a-program-run-at-startup-on-any-computer/)

Comment: It worked, thank you

Comment: glad to help :)

Comment: Instructions from Microsoft's website: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-an-app-to-run-automatically-at-startup-in-windows-10-150da165-dcd9-7230-517b-cf3c295d89dd

Answer (score 0):

1) Launch `RegEdit.exe`

2) Search for  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

3) Add entry like Eclipse `<your eclipse.exe path>`

This will start your Eclipse on startup.

Comment: This may work, but I don't think we should recommend using `regedit` unless it's the only solution.  It appears from the other answer that there is a good solution.

Comment: We can also "Task Scheduler" and selecting the trigger event as when user login